# Route pattern cannot reference variable name "trip_id" more than once

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i am calling an edit page with some id. Its route is as follows:

```
Route::get('edit_vid/{trip_id}', 'HomeController@edit');
```

but when i call this url(route) it gives me following error

```
Route pattern "/video/{trip_id}/{{trip_id}}" cannot reference variable name "trip_id" more than once.
```

i have another route which is totaly different from this one

```
Route::resource('video/{trip_id}', 'HomeController@video');
```

you can see there is no similarity in them except id.. i dont know at where i am doing mistake.. please guide me.. i am beginner in laravel. please help

Comment: You are using {Route::resource} incorrectly. You can't pass a variable to a resource controller. Instead You will need to declare a new route with the verb you need and the parameter. Route::resource only creates several pre-handled routes for you for quick CRUD RESTful acces

Comment: yes.. you are right. thanks .. issue resolved by changing resource to get.

Answer (score 8):

as per  Vipul comment.. i changed

```
Route::resource('video/{trip_id}', 'HomeController@video');
```

to this

```
Route::get('video/{trip_id}', 'HomeController@video');
```

and it worked well.. issue resolved.